# What code is required to launch an iPhone app after a local notification has been scheduled and displayed?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, notifications

I am scheduling a local notification which is firing fine. I need to know how to allow a user to launch my app after the notification has been displayed on screen.

I also need to know how to identify this type of launch to direct the user to a specific view, relevant only to users who have arrived as a result of the notification.

I have been looking at the `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol reference and feel it could be in the area of the `launchOptions` within `-didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, but need a little pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your application will launch automatically, you don't have to do anything in the app itself for that to happen.

If that's not already happening, check that you've specified an alertAction for the notification when you create it - that's the label of the button in the notification alert that opens your app and if you don't set it, the notification alert won't launch the app.

To open a specific view, use the launchOptions and the application:didReceiveRemoteNotification method.

Answer (score 1):

`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` would do the trick.

```objc
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
      UILocalNotification *localNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
     // .. etc
};
```

Keep in mind you also need to implement

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

if you receive a push notification while the app is running (fore- or background)

Answer (score 1):

The launch options should contain the key `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey` which in turn gives you the `UILocalNotification` associated with the notification. Additionally, when scheduling the notification your `UILocalNotification` has the properties `alertBody`, `alertAction` and optionally `alertLaunchImage` which control the information being displayed. The action decribes the button text that launches your app while the body is the information being deisplayed above the buttons. You can supply a specific launch image for this launch to mimic the app already being run.

Also note Bogatyr's answer concerning the cases where your app is not being launched but already there, just suspended.